# Insertar multiples registros desde php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$cantidadcupos=$_POST['cantidad_cupos'];
$idparking=$_POST['idestacionamiento'];

for($i=0; $i<=count($cantidadcupos) ;$i++){

     $query="INSERT INTO  cupos(numero, estado, reserva_id_reserva, estacionamiento_id_estacionamiento) 
                    VALUES ('1','disponible','1','1111')";                   
}

try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Error base de datos2. Porfavor vuelve a intentarlo";
    die(json_encode($response));
}       

$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "El cupo se ha agregado correctamente";
echo json_encode($response);
```

La variable `$cantidad_cupos` recibe un número, y según ese numero necesito realizar las inserciones en la bd, ej: `cantidad_cupos=20` y que realice 20 registros, pero con el código que tengo no logro realizar eso, creo que me falta una transformación de la variable o algo por el estilo, pero no logro dar con la respuesta.

Comment: Debes ejecutar la query dentro del bucle, es decir, tantas veces como inserts necesites hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por partes:

Si `$cantidadcupos` es un número, tu función `count($cantidadcupos)` está devolviendo 1, posiblemente. [Esa función](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) está diseñada para contar elementos de un objeto con propiedad `Countable` o un `Array`.

Luego, [la función execute](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) `$stmt->execute($query_params)` no toma ningún argumento si se hace como llamada a objetos, es decir, te sobra el `$query_params` (que además no veo declarado en ningún sitio).

Y por último, tu query está siendo sobreescrita con cada iteración del bucle..., estás escribiendo sobre `query` múltiples veces sin ejecutarlo. Quizás quieras saber que puedes hacer el `prepare` una sola vez, y el `execute` varias veces sin tener que volver a prepararla.

Además que no lance una excepción no significa que se haya realizado correctamente, `execute` devuelve **True** o **False** dependiendo del éxito de la operación. Eso es lo que debes comprobar.

Comment: esa variable debería convertirla en un array entonces para que realice la acción que yo quiero, o de alguna otra forma, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Bueno, realmente, si lo que necesitas es un número, simplemente pasa un número mediante el $POST y pon la variable tal cual en tu bucle, PHP la convertirá por ti si es algo que pueda ser casteado a un número, aunque también puedes usar la función [int val](http://php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php) si quieres asegurarte.

Comment: me ha funcionado como tu dices, muchas gracias amigo, tenia la duda de preguntar por aquí, y estuve muchas horas buscando la solución, gracias nuevamente.